# java downloading file, prevent second download till first is done

Tags: java

I'm downloading multiple file from my website to update an application, the download is fine but when there is multiple updates it downloads them all at once. I want to to only download the second one once the first download is finished, how would i go about this?

This is how they are downloaded

```
        if (!fullyUpdated) {
            // upadateTextFile(array);
            array.remove(0);
            array.removeAll(arrayUpdated);
            System.out.println("Result: " + array);

            for (Double num : array) {
                download("http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/updates/" + num + ".zip", num);
            }
        }
```

and

```
public void download(String address, Double num) {
    progressBar.setValue(0);
    try {
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask(this, address, num);
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
        task.execute();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

This is the DownloadTask file
http://pastebin.com/UV9c4vnK
and the HTTPDownloadUtil
http://pastebin.com/TcPRw2eD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing each download in a specific thread. They all work in an asynchronous manner. You should move the foreach-loop into the doInBackground-method of your WorkerThread. Otherwise a Thread is started for each element in num.

You should add the Double-Array to the constructor of DownloadTask instead of a single Double-Value.

Answer (score 1):

Your download is executed in another [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), this causes data to be downloaded simultaneously.

The Thread management is delegated to *SwingWorker*, the class extended by DownloadTask.

To prevent *SwingWorker* to download in background, you could try removing the *SwingWorker* extension, removing the Override annotation, changing the name of *doInBackground* method and making him include the *done* method (you won't need this callback anymore).